# @XmlIDREF and @XmlID how to marshal nested collection?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using below JAXB dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have a wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "trainings")
public class ArrayListWrapper {
    private List<TrainingEntity> trainings = new ArrayList();
    //getters & setters here
}
```

TrainingEntity has a property:

```
@XmlIDREF
@XmlElementWrapper
public Set<ArticleEntity> getArticleEntities() { 
    return articleEntities; 
}
```

ArticleEntity has properties:

```
@JsonIgnore
@XmlID
public String getStringId() {
    return article_id.toString();
}

@XmlIDREF
public Set<SectionEntity> getSectionEntitySet() { 
    return sectionEntitySet; 
}
```

SectionEntity has property:

```
@JsonIgnore
@XmlID
public String getStringId() {
    return section_id.toString();
}
```

I have configured resource:

```
// return all trainings => xml
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/all/xml")
public ArrayListWrapper getAllTrainingXml() {
    ArrayListWrapper w = new ArrayListWrapper();
    w.setTrainings(trainingRestService.getAllTrainings());
    return w;
}
```

In output XML is **ignored** collection **sectionEntitySet**:

[xml view snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFmhD.png)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You snippets don't quite explain, what you are getting now and what do you want to get.

Comment: @lexicore I have updated the post, thx for any suggestions

Comment: Sorry, your example is not verifiable/complete, I can't directly run it. It is unclear how you construct your objects or marshal them.

Comment: I have also added to post how I create a resource.